# Embedded GlassFish 3.1 No longer able to statically get server reference

Tags: glassfish-embedded

I am working with the new [embeddable api](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/nonav/apidocs/) in GlassFish 3.1 and have come across a problem.

Previously using the old [embedded api](http://javadoc.glassfish.org/v3/apidoc/org/glassfish/api/embedded/Server.html) I could call a static method to get a currently running server.

```
org.glassfish.api.embedded.Server.getServer(serverName)
```

With the new embeddable api there is only a method to get a new server

```
GlassFish glassfish = GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap().newGlassFish(glassfishProperties)
```

I have a requirement to be able to use the CommandRunner to create a file user in an instance of embedded glassfish that has been started elsewhere.